# Numerical integration of symbolic differentiation - MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, numerical-integration, calculus, differentiation

The following is a MATLAB problem.

Suppose I define an function f(x,y).
I want to calculate the partial derivative of f with respect to y, evaluated at a specific value of y, e.g., y=6. Finally, I want to integrate this new function (which is only a function of x) over a range of x.

As an example, this is what I have tried

`syms x y;
f = @(x, y) x.*y.^2;
Df = subs(diff(f,y),y,2);
Int = integral(Df , 0 , 1)`,

but I get the following error.

`Error using integral (line 82)
First input argument must be a function
handle.`

Can anyone help me in writing this code?

Comment: Generally when a software throws an error is it of good practise reading it, because it tells you what is the reason of thee error and where is it. You should try it. Additionally, if you want help from someone else, telling them which error you get also helps a lot!

Comment: @Ander Biguri Question has been updated!

Comment: What I get is "diff is not a supported class for function handle". Which means you cannot use diff in a f=@ ... Maybe aMatlab version is different? mine is 2013b

Comment: hmmm, strange. This may be because MATLAB is accessing the old 'diff' function, https://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/diff.html

Comment: What do you mean by "old"? http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html this is 2014b docs.

Comment: My bad, I suppose you do `syms x y` before the piee f code. I suggest you try to post everything that is relevant next time ;)

Comment: Ahh, yes these were predefined in my work space. Sorry. The question has now been edited.

Comment: You're mixing numerical quadrature (`integral`) with symbolic differentiation (`sym/diff`). Choose either numeric or symbolic or be very careful going between the two. Use `int` (`sym/int`) to symbolically integrate.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem, `matlabFunction` was required.  The solution looks like this:

```
syms x y
f = @(x, y) x.*y.^2;
Df = matlabFunction(subs(diff(f,y),y,2));
Int = integral(Df , 0 , 1);
```

Comment: Is this an answer or are you trying to clarify your question?

Comment: @rayryeng It's an answer.

Comment: A neater method would probably be to avoid the `subs` call in the `matlabFunction`, and simply make `Df` a function of `x` and `y`, then set up your integral like `integral(@(x) Df(x,2),0,1)`. But `matlabFunction` is exactly the right function to be using here.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it all symbolic, using [`sym/int`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html):

```
syms x y;
f = @(x, y) x.*y.^2;
Df = diff(f,y);
s = int(Df,x,0,1)
```

which returns `y`. You can substitute `2` in for `y` here or earlier as you did in your question. Not that this will give you an exact answer in this case with no floating-point error, as opposed to `integral` which calculated the integral numerically.

When Googling for functions in Matlab, make sure to pay attention what toolbox they are in and what classes (datatypes) they support for their arguments. In some cases there are overloaded versions with the same name, but in others, you may need to look around for a different method (or devise your own).